# Giving an image a width and a height in html

Tags: html, image, height, width

I'm validating my HTML 5 pages and I get a lot of errors because I specified the `width` and `height` of my images in percentage. I though that this was the best way because if I specify it in pixels it won't resize when the site is viewed on a smaller device.

What's the correct way to specify the width and height of an image in HTML?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show to us your way to make that? With code it's more simply to help.

Comment: Can you open the new question you posted? The answer is here: **http://jsbin.com/rivovilili/edit?html,css,output**

Answer (score 0):

If the original image is the aspect ratio that you want then just specify the with % and the height will change automatically.  Make sure that the height of the parent div does not have a specified height as that may cause some problems.  Also positioning of the rest of the page should be relative.